# Calling PHP functions dynamically?

Tags: php, switch-statement, shortcut

Don't know if I worded the question right, but basically what I want to know is if there is an easier (shorter) way of doing the following:

```
switch( $type ) {
    case 'select': $echo = $this->__jw_select( $args ); break;
    case 'checkbox': $echo = $this->__jw_checkbox( $args ); break;
    case 'radio': $echo = $this->__jw_radio( $args ); break;
    case 'input': $echo = $this->__jw_input( $args ); break;
    case 'textarea': $echo = $this->__jw_textarea( $args ); break;
    default: return null;
}
```

Is there any way I could do something like `$echo = $this->__jw_{$type}( $args );`? I tried this code but of course, it failed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$field = "__jw_$type";
$echo = $this->{$field}($args);
```

or even more simply,

```
$echo = $this->{"__jw_$type"}($args);
```

Comment: no offense butm you should also note that this is not a good solution.

Comment: If you are going to do it this way I would at least use a white list of valid function names and check that it is present before actually calling the function. ie: if (in_array($field, array('input','radio',...) {...}

Comment: Honestly it doesn't really matter - the `else` of that `if` would generally be something along the lines of "trigger an error"... which will happen anyways if the method doesn't exist. Adding a unique prefix to the method name insures you won't get collision with something that's not supposed to be invoked (assuming you do it properly), so that's not an issue either.

Comment: Don't worry, I have a 'valid types' array that I check against before calling these methods. I chose your answer because it is the only one-liner posted and it works. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$method = "__jq_$type";
$echo = $this->$method($args);
```

Alternatively, use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$method = "__jq_$type";
$echo = call_user_func(array($this, $method), $args);
```

Of course, there's no validation on the method name here.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you could do it, here's one:

```
if(method_exists($this, "__jw_$type"))
{
    $echo = $this->{"__jw_$type"}($args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$action = "__jw__$type";
$this->$action($args);
```

Of course, you'll really want to verify that `$type` is an allowed type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$type = '__jw_'.$type;
if(method_exists($type,$this))
   $this->{$type}($args);
```